# MEAN.js - Redirect user after signin - Works locally but not when deployed

Tags: javascript, meanjs

Im trying to redirect users after signup but for whatever reason it works locally and not when deployed

Heres the function and the `$window.location.href = '/settings/picture';`  has no effect when deployed

```
$scope.signup = function (isValid) {
  $scope.error = null;

  if (!isValid) {
    $scope.$broadcast('show-errors-check-validity', 'userForm');

    return false;
  }

  $http.post('/api/auth/signup', $scope.credentials).success(function (response) {
    // If successful we assign the response to the global user model

    $scope.authentication.user = response;

    // And redirect to avatar selection screen
    $window.location.href = '/settings/picture'; 


  }).error(function (response) {
    $scope.error = response.message;
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `res.render('/settings/picture', {title: whatever title})` inside your post('/api/auth/signup') route instead of using $window.location.href in your controller

or try giving complete address like $window.location.href = "http://domain.com/settings/pictures.html"